# How to create Local database cache in VS2012?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2012

There are several threads about this,. but i have so far been unable to find any solution.

I am trying to create a local database (SQL Server CE) that will sync with a SQL Server database (SQL Server 2012).

Simple, add a local database cache to your project in VS. Nopes, MS has acknowledged that the missing Local Database Cache in VS2012 is a bug, but for the last year they seem to have done nothing to fix it.

It is becoming increasingly unclear to me whether CE 4.0 even supports *any* form of synchronisation, MS simply states it doesn't, some sites say it's easy to implement (but they skip 7 steps towards that so i don;t consider that any solution).

I have installed ErikEJ's SQL Server Compact Toolbox from http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/releases/view/80269 but it will not let me add a Local Database Cache (The generate local database cache option is there, but it is grayed out???)

It mentioned that options were unavailable because SQL Server CE 3.5 was not installed, so I installed that as well (next to SQL Server CE 4.0)

I still cannot select "Generate Local Database Cache", and selecting either a 4.0 or 3.5 SQL Server CE database, I see the "Sync Framework Tools" option, but the three items under it are... again grayed out.

I am slowly getting to the point of losing my pacifistic nature...

Is there anybody who could point me into a direction that would enable me to (simply???) sync my data between a client SQL Server CE database and a master SQL Server DB?

A sub-question that might lead to something: would anyone know why the option to "Create Local Database Cache" in the SQL Server Compact Toolbox is grayed out, disabled, impossible to use, although in every screenshot i see it is happily enabled?
Edit: This has been solved by installing Sync Framework 2.1
(4.0 has been discontinued for ages, so it seems we need to go back to 2.1. I am slowly starting to lose my sense of time - and my sanity :( )

Answer (score 0):

That seem to be working on in visual studio 2008 everything there 2012 and 2013 all options for local database and local database cache are missing

Answer (score 0):

you can install the plug in for SQL Compact edition for visual studio 2012 and 2013 from 
[visual studio gallery](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0e313dfd-be80-4afb-b5e9-6e74d369f7a1?SRC=Featured)

[sql server compact edition tools](http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/releases/view/104096)